# How to delete changset from user story model using WS API?

Tags: extjs, rally, code-rally

Is their way to delete  changsets from user story model using WS API.
for one of my user story i have not related changset links i have delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You might find this App:

https://github.com/markwilliams970/changeset-utils/tree/master/Apps/Artifact-Changeset-Helper

A useful example for changeset operations on Artifacts with AppSDK